# Integers as even numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are even numbers? 
Can we say  $-2, -4$, etc are even numbers?
I have seen Wikipedia simple English article on this yet it doesn't make sense.

Comment: $-2 / 2 = -1$ so $-2$ is an even integer. So is $0$ btw. What doesn't make sense?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?  $-2 = 2*(-1)$ and $-4 = 2*(-2)$ so, yes,  $0, -2, -4, -6, etc$ are all even numbers.  Why would this be in the least bit surprising or strange.  Shouldn't this be *exactly* what anyone would think?

Answer (score 1):

$-2=2(-1)$ and $-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, hence, $-2$ is an even number. Similarly for $-4$. Note that an integer can be zero, positive, or negative.

An integer, $x$ is an even number if we can find an integer $k$ such that $x=2k$.

Given an integer, divide it by $2$, if the remainder is $0$, it is an even number.

Answer (score 0):

> What are even numbers?

Integers that are evenly divisible by $2$.  Or in other words, numbers of the form $n = 2*k$ where $k$ is some integer.

As $\mathbb Z = \{..... -4, -3,-2,-1 ,0 , 1 ,2,3,4,.....\}$ then the even numbers will be $2$ times all of those.  $\{......, -8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8, ....\}$.

> Can we say −2,−4, etc are even numbers?

Yes.

> I have seen Wikipedia simple English article on this yet it doesn't make sense.

Why not?

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_number

"An even number is an integer which is "evenly divisible" by two. This means that if the integer is divided by 2, it yields no remainder. Zero is an even number because zero divided by two equals zero, which despite not being a natural number, is an integer. **Even numbers are either positive or negative.**"

Why does that not make perfect sense?